# Overloading the QDataStream << and >> operators for a user-defined type

Tags: c++, qt, operator-overloading, iostream

I have a an object I'd like to be able to read and write to/from a QDataStream. The header is as follows:

```
class Compound
{
public:
    Compound(QString, QPixmap*, Ui::MainWindow*);
    void saveCurrentInfo();
    void restoreSavedInfo(QGraphicsScene*);

    void setImage(QPixmap*);

    QString getName();

private:
    QString name, homeNotes, addNotes, expText;
    Ui::MainWindow *gui;
    QPixmap *image;        

    struct NMRdata
    {
        QString hnmrText, cnmrText, hn_nmrText, hn_nmrNucl, notes;
        int hnmrFreqIndex, cnmrFreqIndex, hn_nmrFreqIndex,
        hnmrSolvIndex, cnmrSolvIndex, hn_nmrSolvIndex;
    }*nmr_data;

    struct IRdata
    {
        QString uvConc, lowResMethod,
            irText, uvText, lowResText, highResText,
            highResCalc, highResFnd, highResFrmla,
            notes;
    int irSolvIndex, uvSolvIndex;
    }*ir_data;

    struct PhysicalData
    {
        QString mpEdit, bpEdit, mpParensEdit, bpParensEdit,
            rfEdit, phyText, optAlpha,
            optConc, elemText, elemFrmla,
            notes;
        int phySolvIndex, optSolvIndex;
    }*physical_data;   
};
```

For all intents and purposes, the class just serves as an abstraction for a handful of QStrings and a QPixmap. Ideally, I would be able to write a QList to a QDataStream but I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing this.

If operator overloading is a suitable solution, would writing code like

```
friend QDataStream& operator << (QDataStream&,Compound) { ... }
```

be a potential solution? I'm very open to suggestions! Please let me know if any further clarification is needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you've answered your own question! The stream operator

```
QDataStream& operator<<( QDataStream&, const Compound& )
```

will work fine. In the implementation you just use the existing stream operators on `QDataStream` to serialise the individual bits of your `Compound`. Some Qt classes define non-member `QDataStream` operators too. `QString` is one and so is `QList` so it looks like you're sorted!

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I was able to overload the << operator, but I'm still having trouble with the >>. Would the method signature be the same as above or will it have different parameters?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to overload the "extract" operator >>, your signature must be:

```
QDataStream & operator >> (QDataStream & in, MyClass & class);
```

Hope it helps.